# airmon-ng shows empty results in Backtrack 5 R3

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, vmware, backtrack

I installed VMWare Workstation 10 and Backtrack 5 R3 64-bit as a virtual machine on it. Currently, I am using Windows 8 64-bit.

When I run `airmon-ng` in Backtrack, it shows empty results.

I searched on Google and configured my network adaptors in VMWare like so:

[image]

[image]

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop. It has a built-in wireless card.

Is it true that Backtrack in VMWare does not detect built-in wireless cards?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why airmon-ng is coming up empty-handed in the guest is that you do not have control of the wireless card, in the guest.The hypervisor sets up a connection that allows you to share your internet connection, but it does so by creating a virtual ethernet interface which is bridged with the host extant connection.

You can double check my words by typing the command "iwconfig", it will show that you have no wifi-capable cards on your VM.

The way to gain access to the wifi doman is by means of a USB wifi adapter. There are many guides about that in Google, there are even small movies on youtube. You only have to learn how to transfer control of USB devices from the host to the guest, and the rest is trivial.